# How do I automatically allow studio display connect to Macbook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, power, thunderbolt-display

Studio display disconnects many times on its own from macbook pro and I'm tired of clicking on "allow" connection to macbook pro.

Does anyone know how can I automatically allow studio display to connect to my macbook pro? I've tried googling but cannot find any settings or maybe system commands which would allow automatic connection to apple studio display.

Also, if anyone can tell me how can I fix "random" disconnects from studio display to macbook pro, would be highly appreciated.

What I've tried so far:

- Updating both macbook pro and studio display to latest software/firmware updates.
- Plugged power cable together with studio display thunderbolt cable.("double-charging)

Comment: In *Privacy and Security*, what is your setting for "Allow Accessories to Connect"?